# Using Objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am recieving an object from a websocket,

```
const client = new    
W3CWebSocket("ws://ABCD:9080/user");
```

I want to access values from the object and display it on the browser.

```
const [object, setObject] = useState(""); 
   

    client.onopen = () => {
      console.log("Connected");
    };

    client.onmessage = (e) => {
      const newObj = JSON.parse(e.data);
```

Next I want to set new state with the object I recieved.

```
setObject(newObj.data);
```

Next, I want to map through that object and access the values inside it:

```
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        {Object.keys(object).map((objKey, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <p> {objKey} : {object[objKey]}</p>
            </div>
        ))}
        <DataTable object = { object } />
      </div>
    );
```

How do I map through the object and display the values I need on the browser.
I think I'm missing something since nothing is getting displayed n my browser.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to apply what the answers are suggesting since it invalidates existing answers. If the answers have fixed part of the issue, but you're getting a new issue, please consider accepting the answer and asking a new question regarding the new issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `Object.keys(setObject)` where, `setObject` is a function, and will return an empty array `[]`.
Use `Object.keys(object)` instead

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Navbar />
    {Object.keys(object).map((objKey, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p> {objKey} : {object[objKey]}</p>
        </div>
    ))}
    <DataTable object = { object } />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now "
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: That might be because while setting`setObject(newObj.data)`, `newObj.data` can be either null or undefined. `console.log(newObject.data)` before setting the state to see `newObj`'s value

Answer (score 1):

You are passing setObject instead of object in Object.keys()

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer. Please use the comments section for this.

Comment: I believe it's due to SO's silly restriction which only allow comment section for user with 50 reputation and above @BrianThompson

Comment: I'm sure that's true, but it doesn't make it ok. After the edit it does appear to be answering the question though.

Comment: I'm getting this error now " TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: The answer was already there, but with a remark before. If it is against the rule, I'll avoid that in the future.