# Object in useState hook React

Tags: reactjs

I have a websocket connection, the ws delivers objects and I need to access the objects and pass its values as props so I can use these in my other components.

```
const client = new W3CWebSocket("ws://QWERTY:9080/user");

export default function App() {
  const [object, setObject] = useState(""); 
   
useEffect(() => {
  client.onopen = () => {
    console.log("Connected");
  };

  client.onmessage = (e) => {
    const newObj = JSON.parse(e.data); 
    setObject(newObj);
    console.log(newObj);        

  };

  client.onclose = () => {
    console.log("Closed...");
  };

  
  return () => {
    
  }
}, [])  


    return (
      <div className="App">
        
        <Navbar />
        {Object.keys(object).map((objKey, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <p> {objKey} : {object[objKey]}</p>
            </div>
        ))}
        
        <DataTable object = { object } />
     </div>
    );
}
```

I am trying to display the object values on my browser. But I am getting the following error `"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child"`

The Websocket gives this object: `{Snapshot: {Name: "AppInfo", DataHeader: Array(24), Data: Array(47)}}`

Comment: What is the object that you're trying to display?  If one of its properties is itself an object, what do you expect `{object[objKey]}` to display and why?

Comment: The websocket is returning an object like this,    {Name: "AppInfo", DataHeader: Array(24), Data: Array(47)}

Comment: These questions look oddly similar... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68909640/using-objects-in-react/68909687?noredirect=1#comment121783841_68909687

Comment: Yeah, I was told to post a different question If I was facing other issues. None of the answers seemed to solve my problem and there is not much available regarding handling objects from websockets. So I had to ask another question.

Comment: @Draco did you make a new user for the new question??

Answer (score 0):

Issue is at line where you are using **useState** hook, because initial value in the state you are passing is of string type and you are setting state of object type so change the code like below it will work :-

```
const client = new W3CWebSocket("ws://QWERTY:9080/user");

export default function App() {
const [object, setObject] = useState(); // here pass null value or default object type value 

useEffect(() => {
  client.onopen = () => {
  console.log("Connected");
 };

client.onmessage = (e) => {
  const newObj = JSON.parse(e.data); 
  setObject(newObj);
  console.log(newObj);        
};

client.onclose = () => {
  console.log("Closed...");
};


  return () => {  
  }
}, [])  


return (
  <div className="App">
    
    <Navbar />
    {object && Object.keys(object).map((objKey, index) => ( // add null check over here.
        <div key={index}>
          <p> {objKey} : {object[objKey]}</p>
        </div>
    ))}
    
    <DataTable object = { object } />
 </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: If i pass null value, I get the following error :TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object. And, if I pass an empty object in useState({}), I get: 
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: so pass default value.

Comment: Do you mean default object values I'm getting from the socket?

Comment: @SunnyGoel setting empty string as the initial state will not raise this error, and I don't think that's causing the issue `Object.keys("")` will result in an empty array, which looking at this code, won't throw any the provided error.

Comment: yes because in the html code when first time it render you are trying to iterate over the object keys so add a default value or add null check over there.

Comment: But my object returns a huge set of key-value pairs

Comment: add null check in the html code, i have edit the above answers , check that for reference.

Comment: But in JS idoesn't the The typeof null return an 'object'?

Comment: yes but passing null inside the Object.keys(null) result the following error :- cannot convert undefined or null to object. that's why  i am saying add null check in the html.

Comment: How do I check for null in the return function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236359/discussion-between-draco-and-sunny-goel).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to render an Object inside the `<p>` tag.

```
<p> {objKey} : {object[objKey]}</p>
```

According to your `object` example: `{Snapshot: {Name: "Snapshot", DataHeader: Array(24), Data: Array(47)}}`, `{objKey}` is `"Snapshot"`, which can be rendered, but `object[objKey]` is equivalent to `object["Snapshot"]` which yeilds: `{Name: "AppInfo", DataHeader: Array(24), Data: Array(47)}`.

And this finally results in trying to render:

```
<p> Snapshot : {Name: "AppInfo", DataHeader: Array(24), Data: Array(47)}</p>
```

which is not valid. You can convert it into string using `JSON.stringify()` If you just want to show the Object's representation as text:

```
const client = new W3CWebSocket("ws://QWERTY:9080/user");
    
export default function App() {
  const [object, setObject] = useState(""); 
   
useEffect(() => {
  client.onopen = () => {
    console.log("Connected");
  };

  client.onmessage = (e) => {
    const newObj = JSON.parse(e.data); 
    setObject(newObj);
    console.log(newObj);        

  };

  client.onclose = () => {
    console.log("Closed...");
  };

  
  return () => {
    
  }
}, [])  


    return (
      <div className="App">
        
        <Navbar />
        {Object.keys(object).map((objKey, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <p> {objKey} : {JSON.stringify(object[objKey])}</p>
            </div>
        ))}
        
        <DataTable object = { object } />
     </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I do not want it as a string. I need to access the values of the object as props in my other components.

Comment: Your original question refers to the snippet throwing `"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child"`. I pointed out that the line `<p> {objKey} : {object[objKey]}</p>` is throwing the error. And converting it to string is just an example to mitigate the thrown error.